# Content type-error when using Zend_Http_Client

Tags: php, post, zend-framework, zend-http-client

I'm trying to send data to Google Analytic's collector with Zend_Http_Client and POST. I have an array `$postParams` that's including my tracking-ID, cid and hit types and I add the values of this array to my client via `setParameterPost()`.

Here's the relevant part of my Action:

```php
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://ssl.google-analytics.com/debug/collect');
foreach ($postParams as $postParam => $postValue) {
    $client->setParameterPost($postParam, $postValue);
}
$response = $client->request();
```

When calling this script I get the following error:

> Cannot handle content type '' automatically. Please use Zend_Http_Client::setRawData to send this kind of content.

It's thrown in the `_prepareBody()` method in Zend_Http_Client. When I'm adding an `echo($this->enctype); die();` there, I receive `NULL`.

I'd add `$client->setEncType();` to my code but the data is plain.
Has anyone an idea what I'm missing here? Do I really have to use `setRawData`?

Thanks in advance!

Update: `$client->setParameterPost('postParams', $postParams);` won't work too. It throws the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer brought me back on track: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7407491/3218828

```
$rawData = '';
foreach ($postParams as $postParam => $postValue) {
    if ($rawData !== '') {
        $rawData .= '&';
    }
    $rawData .= $postParam . '%5B%5D=' . $postValue;
}
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setRawData($rawData);
$client->setUri('https://ssl.google-analytics.com/debug/collect');
$client->request(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
```